# oxid import old data SQL

Tags: sql, import, oxid

I have an old oxid-version. I exported my old seo-data from the table "oxseo" to get the keywords and description for each article. Now i want to import these fields in my new version of the shop. My articles are already there, but not the seodata.

My first idea was to collect all the data i need from a csv-export of my old data.
For example, my output array could look something like:

```
$article  = array();
$keywords = array();
$desc     = array();

foreach($line as $l) {
    $keywords[$i] = current_keyword
    $desc[$i]     = current_description
    $oxid[$i]     = current_oxid
}
```

So lets just assume I already have my filled array.

If i check the oxid's, they are still the same. So, from my exported CSV, picking a random OXID, looking for it in my new DB shows me the correct article.

Now my first thought was, to look in oxobject2seodata. I know that the data for the articles are stored in there, but i can't find a way to connect those, since the "oxid" from the old version is not the same as the objectId in the new version. In oxarticles, however, there is no "objectId".

Thank you in advance for any hints and tips

Comment: I do not understand the problem. if you can connect the old and the new oxid, you can simply merge these two datatables?

Answer (score 0):

The field OXID in oxarticles table should match the field OXOBJECTID in oxobject2seodata table.

```
SELECT oa.OXID, o2s.* from oxobject2seodata o2s, oxarticles oa WHERE o2s.OXOBJECTID = oa.OXID AND oa.OXID = '[OXID-of-article]';
-- or
SELECT o2s.* from oxobject2seodata o2s WHERE o2s.OXOBJECTID = '[OXID-of-article]';
```